# NullPointerException when using DiskLruCache

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When I used DiskLruCache I get a NullPointerException:
First I get a usable cache directory (external if available, internal otherwise) using the following code:

```
private static File getDiskCacheDir(Context context, String uniqueName) {
    String cachePath;
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())
            || !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
        cachePath = context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath();
    } else {
        cachePath = context.getCacheDir().getPath();
    }
    return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
}
```

But when I upload my application to the Application Market, I get the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException,Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getPath()' on a null object reference,DiskCacheManager.java,47

In the DiskCacheManager.java only the above method has the "getPath()".
It may lead to NullPointerException? What should I do to avoid it?

Sorry, the above method is used in the below function, and the line 47 is:

> cachePath = context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath();

```
private static DiskLruCache getDiskLruCache(Context context) {
    DiskLruCache mDiskLruCache = null;
    try {
        File cacheDir = getDiskCacheDir(context, "prod");
        if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
        mDiskLruCache = DiskLruCache.open(cacheDir, getAppVersion(context), 1, 60 * 1024 * 1024);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mDiskLruCache;
}
```

Because the crash occured during the test, it may running in the virtual machine, that may cause context.getExternalCacheDir() be null?

Comment: Well which of the two is causing this?

Comment: What is line 47?

Comment: `When I used DiskLruCache I get a NullPointerException` .???? There is no code for DiskLruCache. Where are you talking about?

Comment: `when I upload my application to the Application Market, I get the error:` ?? During upload? During upload your code is not executed. What do you mean?

Comment: The line 47 is the former getPath()

Answer (score 0):

The thing seems to be you're using `context.getExternalCacheDir()` or `context.getCacheDir()` and calling `.toPath()` on it without checking if it's null.

Add a check for `context.getExternalCacheDir() != null` before you call `toPath()` on it to make sure you don't get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, I did not checked it`s null or not , but do you know why the context.getExternalCacheDir() may be null?

Comment: Did you add the permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to your manifest?

Comment: Yes, have added

Comment: Then try debugging the code, put a breakpoint on that line and go into it to see getExternalCacheDir to see what's happening. It usually returns a null if the permission is not there or if the device or emulator has no external storage. Check if you don't have a typo in the permision